# Accelerometer readings of zero every other ReadingChanged invocation

Tags: microsoft-band

I adapted slightly the Accelerometer sample from the SDK to save the readings, and it looks like every other reading gives x:0, y:0, z:0... is that to be expected?

Will there be an option to specify a sample time, so I can get readings every *n* milliseconds, for instance?

Comment: Do you mean specify a different reporting interval than those supported via. .ReportingInterval? 16, 32 and 128ms). The every second reading being 0 is not expected- if the problem persists I would normalize the readings (I always do that for accuracy). For specific intervals you could do a manual pull w a ticker, or a circular queue grabbing at specific intervals and purging the buffer. Maybe I misunderstood the question, but I hope this helps :) Let me know if I got the question right and I'll add some code and fill out this reply :))

Comment: I'm getting the exact same behavior since upgrading to latest Band SDK, developing on Windows Phone 8.1.  I'm specifying the a ReportingInterval as 16ms and every other reading has the exact same timestamp as the previous reading but x,y,z are all zero.  This definitely seems like a new bug since it use to work fine with the preview SDK.

Comment: I missed ReportingInterval, so it was running at whatever the default was... the every-other-zero readings are the bigger issue. I can simply ignore them  for now.

Comment: Tested with 2 bands now and got the same issue. Seem like a SDK bug. :(

Answer (score 0):

What platform are you using the SDK with?

As for different polling intervals, that is not exposed currently. You can add feature requests for future Microsoft Band SDK versions at: http://microsofthealth.uservoice.com/

Comment: sorry should have mentioned... Windows Store app using VS 2015 RC on Win 10 Insider Preview (10074).